# Count elements of list from queryset

Tags: python, django, list

I get a queryset from a model that saves the data to a `charfield`. The charfield is displayed on a form as `MultipleChoiceField` with a `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget. The max amount of choices is 5.

I want to count the number of elements in the queryset. Each queryset can vary in the amount of the elements in the list. Now, when I get `len` of the list, the value is 5 times the amount of elements. Is the list in the dict not a list but something else? When I create a list manually without the queryset and get `len` of said list, the value is correct. E.g. list with 3 elements returns 3.

`query = MyModel.objects.all().values('myvalue')`

```
print(query[0])
{'myvalue': "['3']"}
print(query[1])
{'myvalue': "['1', '4']"}

print(query[0]['myvalue']
['3']
print(query[1]['myvalue']
['1', '4']

print(len(query[0]['myvalue']))
5

print(len(query[1]['myvalue']))
10
```

Comment: So instead of `5 and 10` you are expecting `1 and 2` right ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I expect and want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[ast module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)** to convert the string list to list object and get the len

```
import ast

a = ast.literal_eval("['3']")      #print(len(ast.literal_eval(query[0]['myvalue'])))
b = ast.literal_eval("['1', '4']")
print len(a)  # returns 1
print len(b)  # returns 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a charfield to store the data, everything while being stored willl get converted to a char so you can't use len on it directly.
You can use use a JSONField or ListField if your're using postgres as your db backend.
If you have to use a CharField or a TextField then you'll need to first convert it back. You can create a custom field inheriting from TextField which will do it everywhere you use it or just use json.loads() after you load the data from the database